# Pack squares into a rectangle

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a rectangle width x height, and N squares of same unknown size.
I must determine the maximum size of these squares and number of rows and columns to fit perfectly (UPD. I mean not to fill all space, but fill as much space as possible) into the rectangle.

I guess, mathematically it looks like this:

```
x * size <= width                  //x - number of columns
y * size <= height                 //y - number of rows
x * y <= N                         //N - number of squares
size -> max                        //size - size of squares
```

Final result can look like this:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0
```

Where `1` = `squares`, `0` = empty space`.

Actually I saw similar problems, but with predefined size of squares. Also, I wrote some clumsy algorithm, but its results are very unsatisfactory..

**Edit:** My current algorithm:

I tried a lot of variations, but I cant make it work flawlessly for all cases. Actually, I can go through all possible sizes, but I do not like this approach.

```
// to make things more simple I put width as bigger size 
int biggerSize = this.ClientSize.Width;
int lowerSize = this.ClientSize.Height;  
int maxSize = int.MinValue;
int index = 0;
int index2 = 0;

// find max suitable size
for (int i = _rects.Count; i > 0; i--) {
  int size = biggerSize / i;
  int j = (int)Math.Floor((double)lowerSize / size);

  if (i * j >= _boards.Count && size > maxSize) {
    maxSize = size;
    index = (int)i;
    index2 = (int)j;
  }
}

int counter = 0;

// place all rectangles
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < index2; j++) {
    if (counter < _rects.Count) {                                
      _rects[counter].Size = new Size(maxSize, maxSize);
      _rects[counter].Location = new Point(i * maxSize, j * maxSize);
    }

    counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the algorithm you wrote, and describe how the results are unsatisfactory. Is it too slow? Are the results not what you expected? If so, what results did you get, and what results did you expect?

Comment: I *think* I understand what you mean, but just to be sure, could you include some examples? (just the numbers will be fine) Say you have a 24x60 rectangle and N=10, the squares could be of size 12, right? And if N=2, size 24?

Comment: Yes, true. And if N=9 and 24x60 - there will be an empty square. I stated the goal a little incorrectly - not perfect fill, but best possible fill.

Comment: Is the question equivalent to “What is the largest edge size of a square such that N squares will fit inside a W×H rectangle, with no overlap of the squares? (The edges of the squares may lie on the boundary of the rectangle; they do not need to be strictly interior to it, and the edges of the squares may touch/overlap each other.)” Are the rectangle dimensions integers? Do the square sizes have to be integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not consistent.  First, you state the problem as "determine the maximum size of these squares and number of rows and columns to fit **perfectly** into the rectangle." (emphasis added).

But then you give a sample final result that allows empty space.

So which is it?

If you need the squares to fit perfectly in the rectangle with no empty space and no squares extending beyond the bounds of the rectangle, then the size of the maximal square would equal the greatest common divisor of the length and width of the rectangle.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#A_geometric_view

Comment: Sorry. I meant not to fill all space, but fill as much space as possible. 
Thanks for your reply. I can not understand only one thing about it - this method will give me only the maximum size, but I also have predefined number of squares I need to place.

Comment: @DizzyBlack - Well, you know you don't want any squares smaller than the greatest common divisor.  So, if all rectangle and square lengths are ints, then you could just try all square lengths between gcd and min(length, width).

Comment: Okay, I am not sure it is the perfect solution I searched, but anyway, thanks, I will think about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no closed-form formula for this problem. You can't do much better than trying many sizes until you find the best square size, but you can do this in O(log n) time where *n* is the larger dimension in pixels of your rectangle using binary search:

```c
int maximumSquareSize = (int)sqrt(rectangleWidth * rectangleHeight / squareCount);
int squareSize = binarySearchSquareSize(0, maximumSquareSize);

int binarySearchSquareSize(int minimumSquareSize, int maximumSquareSize)
{
  int testedSquareSize = (minimumSquareSize + maximumSquareSize) / 2;
  if (testedSquareSize == minimumSquareSize || testedSquareWidth == maximumSquareSize) return testedSquareSize;
  int squaresPerRow = rectangleWidth / testedSquareSize ;
  int squaresPerColumn = rectangleHeight / testedSquareSize ;
  int totalSquaresFitted = squaresPerRow * squaresPerColumn;
  if (totalSquaresFitted < squareCount)
  {
    return binarySearchSquareSize(minimumSquareWidth, testedSquareWidth);
  }
  else
  {
    return binarySearchSquareSize(testedSquareWidth, maximumSquareWidth);
  }
}
```

The first line is a minor optimization that may save a few loops. It determines the maximum possible square size from the fact that the resultant area of the square times the number of squares must not exceed the area of the rectangle for the answer to be valid. You could also just started with `max(rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight)` instead as the upper bound.

Then, the code performs a binary search between 0 (squares of size 0 will definitely fit in the rectangle) and this maximum, checking if the resulting square fitting would overflow the rectangle, until it reaches the square size where the fit is the most exact possible.