# Calculating maximum square in screen

Tags: java, android, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pack squares into a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627449/pack-squares-into-a-rectangle)

i need to calculate the most efficient size of squares will fill the the screen,

if you look at the below images,  there are different screen sizes and square count. 
I need a algorithm to calculate **x axis square count and y axis square count** which will fill the screen most efficiently (**minimum empty area will be left after filling with squares**).

i looked at the below post but it is not the answer that solves my question

[Pack squares into a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627449/pack-squares-into-a-rectangle)

**1 - Square count can be changed (3-5-10 so on ...)**

**2 - Screen size can be different**

For examples ,

- on 1280 x 800 with 15 square ?
- on 800 x 480 with 12 square ?
- on 600x1024  with 9 square ?
- on 720x1280  with 45 square ?

** I need a algorith which calculate the squares width (height is same with width) **

If you look at differencies beetween image 3 and Image 3-1 you will see that Image 3-1 uses the screen more efective because there are less unused area.

**Image 3**
[image: Image 3]

Or maybe this is a better way to fill:

**Image 3-1**

[image: Image 3 - 1]

If you look at differencies beetween image 4 and Image 4-1 you will see that Image 4-1 uses the screen more efective because there are less unused area.

**Image 4**

[image: Image 4]

** 4. Image must be like below , because there are less unused area on the screen **

**Image 4-1**
[image: Image 4 - 1]

Comment: It is unclear to me, is the number of squares a parameter, known before?

Comment: For example for the third case, filling 3X2 with square sizes 373.3333 is possible. Is it more efficient?

Comment: Yes the square number will be known before calculating

Comment: Can you define your problem more clearly: What do you mean by "filling the screen efficiently"? Are you allowed to have pixels left over on the axes? In your 3rd and 4th examples, do you think those are good solutions? There seem to be much better ways to fit 6 or 20 squares in.

Comment: in third case, it cant be 373.333 because it must be a square

Comment: What do you mean "it must be square"?

Comment: i mean x = y, i see now clearly, for 3. case there are better ways you are right

Comment: @Alan Stokes, please look at the [Edit 1] in the question.

Comment: You haven't explained your question clearly enough to get an answer. What are the constraints? What does "efficiently" mean? What makes the new solution better than the old one? What, fundamentally, are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe the question would be better on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com ? as it is more an algorithm problem than a technical one (not sure)

Comment: @Alan, please look at edit 2, i want after filling screen with score, there should be min unused area on the screen

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you suggest by "efficient" is the larger the area covered by the squares the better.

let :

a : x axis square count

b : y axis square count

s : size of a square (length of one side)

w : width of screen

h : height of screen

c : number of squares to put

then we have

```
a * s <= w
b * s <= h
a * b >= c
```

With these inequalities it is possible to find an upper bound for s.
Examining the forth example given where c = 20, w = 1280 and h = 800

```
a * s <= 1280
b * s <= 800
a * b >= 20
```

a * b = (1280 / s) * (800 / s) >= 20 ---> s^2 <= (1280*800) / 20 ---> s <= 226,27..

With an upper bound for s, we can estimate a and b as;

a * s <= 1280 ---> a ~= 5,6568
b * s <= 800  ---> b ~= 3,53

with these values the inequality a * b >= 20 does not hold.

But both a and b must be whole numbers. Then we try the 4 possibilities that a and b can get :

```
a = 5, b = 3 // round down both
a = 5, b = 4 // one down, one up
a = 6, b = 3 // one down, one up
a = 6, b = 4 // round up both
```

since a * b >= 20 the first and third cases are eliminated to be a valid answer.
Choosing the answer where a = 5, b = 4 follows as the next step since their product is more close to the desired number of squares.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [greatest common factor](http://www.mathsisfun.com/greatest-common-factor.html) between the width and the height of the display.

Since most displays have a ratio of 4:3 or 16:9, the greatest common factor will give you the biggest square that you can use to fill the display area.

In your 400 x 400 pixel display, the greatest common factor is 400, and one square will fill the display.

In your 1280 X 800 pixel display, the greatest common factor is 160.  You'll need 40 squares (8 x 5) to fill the display.

if you want to calculate one greatest common factor for all display sizes, the answer is 1.  Every pixel is a square.  You should calculate a separate greatest common factor for each display size you want to support.

Comment: I think there is one additional constraint that @talhakosen did not express very clearly.  I think he has a fixed number of squares that he wants to display, and the problem is to determine the maximum size of these squares such that the squares can be arranged into a rectangular array (i.e. aligned into rows and columns) and fit completely within the screen rectangle.

Comment: @mbeckish: I agree with you that you've described a different problem than the one I'm understanding from the original poster.  A 4 x 3 arrangement can be sized to fit the majority of display screens, but there will be space left over in a lot of display sizes.

Comment: @mbeckish i dont have fixed size of square. there can be 10 or 15 or 20 squares. I need to calculate square size which will the screen. After filling screen, there will be minumum unused area on the screen as shown in Image 4 - 1.

Comment: @talhakosen - I suggested that you have a fixed **number** of squares, not a fixed **size** of each square.  If that is not the case, and you can have as many squares as you want, and the only goal is to have no unused space, then use greatest common factor.  That will give you squares that cover the entire rectangle, with no empty space.